# System.Threading.Timer causing other Timers to fall behind

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, timer, timeout

My first post here, but this site has answered many questions that I have had in the past.  Hopefully I can give enough detail to explain the issue I am facing as I don't fully understand how all .NET is handling the threads I create!

OK so basically, I have a thread set to run every 1000ms which gets a frame counter from a video encoder and calculate the FPS.  Accuracy is sufficient with a System.Threading.Timer for now though I realise it isn't accurate (often over 1000ms between events).  I also have another Threading.Timer which is running and taking a reading from a network to serial device.  The issue is that if the network device becomes unavailable and the socket timesout on that timer the FPS timers go completely out of sync!  So they were previously executing every 1015ms (measured) but when I start this other Thread.Timer trying to make a socket connection and it fails it causes the FPS counter timers to go totally off (up to 7000ms!!).  Am not quite sure why this should be and really need the FPS counter to run once a second pretty much no matter what.

Bit of code ->

FPS Counter

```
private void getFPS(Object stateInfo)//Run once per second
{
    int frames = AxisMediaControl.getFrames; //Axis Encoder media control
    int fps = frames - prevValue;
    prevValue = frames;
    setFPSBar(fps, fps_color); //Delegate to update progress bar for FPS
}
```

Battery Level Timer

```
while (isRunning)
{
    if (!comm.Connected) //comm is standard socket client
        comm.Connect(this.ip_address, this.port);   //Timeout here     causes     other timer threads to go out of sync

if (comm.Connected)
{
    decimal reading = comm.getBatt_Level();
    //Calculate Readings and update GUI
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Reading = " + (int)prog);
break;//Debug

        }
```

This is the code used to connect to the socket currently ->

```
 public Socket mSocket { get; set; }
 public bool Connect(IPAddress ip_address, UInt16 port)
 {
    try
    {
        mSocket.Connect(ip_address, port);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 

    }
    return mSocket.Connected;   
}
```

Hopefully not too ambiguous!

Comment: Why is it a good idea to hide exceptions?

Comment: The software will be used in an environment where there will be alot of timeouts and I don't think that showing a message every 5seconds will be that useful.  I catch the exceptions when debugging, but I expect the connection to fail sometimes as the network is wireless and dropouts are expected during operation.  What would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest catching `TimeoutException` or whatever specific exception you're concerned about, and allowing the others to propagate. That way, you'll learn what the other exceptions are.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know why your FPS timer is not called for 7s, I can suggest a workaround: Measure the TimeSpan since the last time the FPS value was updated by remembering the Environment.TickCount value. Then, calculate the FPS value as (delta_frames / delta_t).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I do think it is rather odd, wasn't sure if it was related to the thread pool for .NET as when testing the full applicaiton I have about 5 threads counting the frames per second and 4 for the battery reading.  Also at times the software seems to use up to 90 threads in task manager which seems much to high..!  The work around is definately an option, but am hoping I can find the source of the issue if possible!

Comment: 90 threads are way too much. You might be hitting some thread pool limits here causing the timer ping not to be executed. I suggest you look at the threads window in the debugger to see why there are so many threads. Notice, that a Threading.Timer does not block a thread, so this is probably not the cause.

Comment: Just wondering,  when looking at it running it seems many of the threads are created for the socket client so will have to look into that.  It also appears to be using threads to update the interface for the FPS counter (I use a delegate), is this a bad way to update the interface?  As each timer updates through a delegate and this seems to be adding extra threads at runtime.  So when viewing 4 video streams this problem is magnified !

Comment: When a timer is due, your callback is queued to the threadpool. Only while it executes, a thread is used. No thread is used while waiting for the next tick and no thread is used while your callback is in the queue. This is definitely the right approach.

Comment: The battery level timer seems to be in an infinite loop, though. It is using up a thread. As long as you have a small constant amount of them (4) this is not a problem.

Comment: The battery level timer actually breaks out of the loop at the bottom and then is called again by the timer.  I used the while(isRunning) to try and stop them faster, but I will probably remove it as there is likely no need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I fixed it by doing the following.

Used a `System.Timers.Timer` instead and set auto-reset to false.  Each time one of the timers completes I start it again, this means there is only ever one timer for each battery device.  The problem with the initial solution is that the network timeout was causing the threads to stay alive for much longer than the timer interval.  Thus, to ensure the timer interval was met a new thread was spawned more frequently.

During runtime this meant there was about 5-7 threads for each battery timer (whereby 6 are timing out and 1 is about to begin).  Changing to the new timer means there is only one thread now as it should be.

I also added in the code to calculate the FPS based on the time taken (using Stopwatch function for higher accuracy (thanks USR)).  Thanks for the help.  I will have to make sure not to just leave exceptions blank too.